# Finding the sample size from a known sample variance

Tags: statistics

1. For a normal distributed population: N(μ,σ^2), assume σ is a known constant, and we want to construct a 1-α level CI for μ. If we want the length of CI to be at most a, where a is a given positive constant, then what’s the requirement of selecting sample size?
2. Same as question 1, but now σ is unknown. If we know that the sample variance s^2 stables around some level and can be treated as a fixed constant. Then what’s the requirement of selecting sample size?

I'm having trouble with #2, is there a formula that utilizes sample variance to find sample size? Tyia!

Answer (score 0):

If $\bar{x}$ is the mean of a sample of size $n$ from the population, then the confidence interval is $\bar{x} \pm z_\alpha \sigma/\sqrt{n}$ where $z_\alpha$ is such that $P(-z_\alpha \le Z \le z_\alpha) = 1-\alpha$ for a standard normal random variable $Z$. (You need to either use a normal table or a computer to get the value of $z_\alpha$.) So the length of the confidence interval is $2z_a \sigma / \sqrt{n}$, which you can set equal to $a$ and then solve for $n$.

---

If $\sigma$ is unknown, then the confidence interval is $\bar{x} \pm t_\alpha s/\sqrt{n}$ where $t_\alpha$ is such that $P(-t_\alpha \le T \le t_\alpha) = 1-\alpha$ for a $t$-distributed random variable $T$ with $n-1$ degrees of freedom. (Again, you will need to use a table or a computer to compute $t_\alpha$.)

Comment: Thank you, I think I figured out what n should be!